# Python Beautifulsoup: How to download images from a div and then copy it to word document?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-analysis

Here is my code:

```
    for div in panel:
    titleList = div.find('div', attrs={'class': 'panel-heading'})
    imageList = div.find('div', attrs={'class', 'pro-image'})
    descList = div.find('div', attrs={'class': 'pro-desc'})
    print titleList.get_text(separator=u' ')
    print descList.get_text(separator=u' ')
    document.add_heading("%s \t \n" % titleList.get_text(separator=u'  '), level=1)
    document.add_paragraph("%s \t \n" % descList.get_text(separator=u'  '))
```

I want to download the images from:

```
imageList = div.find('div', attrs={'class', 'pro-image'})
```

I then want to copy those downloaded images and copy them into a word document. How do I do this?

Comment: What type of word document?

Comment: It is a docx document.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to download image and then just save it (as a binary data) with proper extension.

Suppose your image is located at http://example/my_image.jpg

```
with open("my_image.jpg", "wb") as img_handle:
    img_data = requests.get("http://example/my_image.jpg")
    img_handle.write(img_data.content)
```

This is just a simple example though. As noted by [t.m.adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7811673/t-m-adam) in the comments, you should use `img_data.content` instead of `img_data.text` for binary data.

As for inserting that image into Word document, you can use any library which provides such functionality. [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) comes up as a first google search result, it may be useful.

Comment: Dont use `response.text` for binary data. Use `response.content` instead.

Comment: Yes but I have like 300+ images to download. And this div is found in 30 pages.

Comment: In that case you'll have to write the program which will crawl the website and look for the images to download.